# How to add App Specific (not Global) Maven Proxy Settings

Tags: java, maven

Ignoring why I would want to do this -- there are valid reasons in my case -- which I don't want to get into.

Is there a way to configure Maven Proxy settings (specifically add a Proxy for dependencies) at the app level (i.e. committed in SCM as part of my Java application , in say something like my pom.xml) ... instead of the more traditional global settings.xml location.

In my case, I would somehow want to include the following settings.xml changes as part of my Java application source code without requiring any changes to global / user level settings.

```
<proxy> 
      <id>optional</id> 
      <active>true</active> 
      <protocol>http</protocol> 
      <host>someotherhost.com</host> 
      <port>8080</port> 
      <nonProxyHosts></nonProxyHosts> 
 </proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using maven profile might help. You may want to look into this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39352043/14269475), could be helpful for your situation.

Comment: Thanks though this still seems to require editing of the Global settings.xml file ... which I don't want to touch, ideally I want the profile settings as part of my java app (in it's individual SCM repo in some way -- pom.xml settings maybe ?).

Answer (score 0):

You can add your own settings.xml to the project. Then you can use it in your build server with the -s parameter.

Comment: Fixes the build server problem -- but I would also want let developers to get this functionality locally without running maven with the parameter and without any required global config changes.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. You haven't described the reasons behind your question. Knowing the whole situation, one might find a better solution.